# SVG vector text stroke is not "finished"

Tags: html, svg, text, path, stroke

Why is that this stroke on my vector text isn't finished on some of letter corners? I made this SVG in Illustrator with 1px stroke and as a picture it's as it is supposed to be. I've tried different fonts but i'm still getting the same problem. I also tried vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke; which helped out a little bit. I tested different stroke-dashoffsets but no luck with that either.

[here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/u69xa8vf/)

```css
path{
stroke-dasharray:500;
opacity:10;
stroke:#000;
animation: animate 4s cubic-bezier(.69,.71,.69,.71);
}

@keyframes animate{
    
    0%{

        opacity=0;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    }
    
20%{

        opacity=0;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    }
    

        100%{
        opacity:10;
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
    
    }
    
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 363.5 122.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 363.5 122.5;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#AF174A;}
    .st1{stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<polygon class="st0" points="189.6,-14.4 189.5,-14.5 189.5,-14.4 "/>
<g>
    <path class="st1" d="M121.9,104.7l-18.1-17.8v17.8h-1.1V67.4h1.1v17.9l18.1-17.9h1.4l-18.9,18.7l18.9,18.7H121.9z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M148.7,67.4v1h-17.2v17.2h15.6v1h-15.6v17.2h17.2v1h-18.2V67.4H148.7z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M164.8,104.7l-10-37.3h1.2l9.4,35.2l10.9-35.2h1.2l11,35.4l9.4-35.4h1.2l-10,37.3h-1.1l-11.1-35.6l-11.1,35.6
        H164.8z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M225.2,67.4v1H208v17.2h15.6v1H208v17.2h17.2v1H207V67.4H225.2z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M258.2,67.5h1.1v37.3h-1.1L235,69.4v35.3h-1.1V67.5h1.1l23.2,35.3V67.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being bitten by a detail of the SVG specification that I am not quite sure about. Is it a bug or a feature? Decide for yourself.

The paths you use end their `d` attributes with a **closepath** command `z`. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand) makes clear that the behavior of strokes at that end point of a path differs whether closepath is used or not:

> When a subpath ends in a "closepath," it differs in behavior from what happens when "manually" closing a subpath via a "lineto" command in how `stroke-linejoin` and `stroke-linecap` are implemented. With "closepath", the end of the final segment of the subpath is "joined" with the start of the initial segment of the subpath using the current value of `stroke-linejoin`. If you instead "manually" close the subpath via a "lineto" command, the start of the first segment and the end of the last segment are not joined but instead are each capped using the current value of `stroke-linecap`.

You can compare the effect of closing or not closing the path in the example below.

```css
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 20;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <path d="M20 20 H 80 V 80 H 20 V 20" />
    <path d="M120 20 H 180 V 80 H 120 z" />
</svg>
```

The default value for `stroke-linecap` is `butt`, which means the stroke simply ends perpendicular to the end of the stroke. Therefor, without closing the path, there remains a gap at the outer corner where a linejoin, if applied, would draw a miter.

Now, your code *has* the closepath command. Why is that final miter not being drawn anyway? You have to read the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#StrokeShape) realy closely for its algorithm for drawing dashes. When computing positions for the dashes, it says

> While position < pathlength:
>
> 1. Set index to (index + 1) mod count.
> 2. Let dashlength be min(dashes<sub>index</sub>, pathlength − position).
> 3. If index mod 2 = 0, then append to positions the pair <position, position + dashlength>.
> 4. Set position to position + dashlength.

No. 2 means, the last dash always ends before or at the end of the path, and never will overshoot. As an algorithm, this makes sense. But the spec also says that each dash starts and ends with the cap shape defined by `stroke-linecap`.

> 1. Let positions be the dash positions for the subpath.
> 2. For each pair <start, end> in positions: (...)
>
>    3. Set dash to be the union of dash and the starting cap shape for the subpath at position start.
>    4. Set dash to be the union of dash and the ending cap shape for the subpath at position end.
>    5. Let index and last be the indexes of the path segments in the subpath at distance start and end along the subpath.
>    6. While index < last:
>
>       1. Set dash to be the union of dash and the line join shape for the subpath at segment index index.
>       2. Set index to index + 1.

It does not mention the start and end of a closed path as a special case. Linejoin s hapes are drawn only *inside* the dashes, but there is always a **cap** shape drawn at their ends, never a **join** shape.

That lead the answerer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945300) to suggest the usage of `stroke-linecap: square`. This works quite well as long as the first and last segment of a path meet perpendicular. But if there is any other angle, like you have it for the letters K and W, you still get improper results. A value of `round` looks smooth, but also differs from the miter effect on the other linejoins.

```css
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 20;
    stroke-dasharray: 250;
    stroke-linecap: square;
}
.smoothed {
   stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <path d="M20 20 H 80 V 80 H 20 z" />
    <path d="M120 20 H 180 V 80 H 140 z" />
    <path d="M220 20 H 280 V 80 H 240 z" class="smoothed" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Got much more information on SVGs than i expected.